# How can i get value from 3rd column of listview

Tags: c#

How can i get value from 3rd column of listview in C#. i am getting value from 1st and 2nd column of list view but when i try to get value from 3rd column it give me error. no index found. I have created 3 columns in my listview.

My code is given below.

```
string std_name = listView1.Items[count].SubItems[1].Text;
int rollNumber = int.Parse(listView1.Items[count].SubItems[0].Text);
string marks = listView1.Items[count].SubItems[2].Text;  // error is takeplace in this line.
```

Comment: Use a debugger (Press F5 in Visual Studio) and find out how many `Items` and `SubItems` there are, so you can see what went wrong.

Comment: You have not posted that code where u have added subitems... May be the problem is there.. if the 3rd subitem is not added in that item then it could not be found and gives error... even u have created 3 columns.

Comment: is this winform application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating 3 columns does not fills values in all the columns,

First check if a particular ListViewItem (Row) has atleast 3 sub items, you can do so by

```
var colCount = listView1.Items[item_index].SubItems.Count;
```

if the value is `<= 2` then you have not added the `3rd` value yet in the column.

---

Answering to you comment

```
if (listView1.Items[item_index].Count == 2)
(
    listView1.Items[item_index].SubItems.Add("DEFAULT_VALUE_OF_THIRD_ITEM");
)
```

Comment: it returns me 2. how can i add 3rd column?

Comment: @user3696811 - answered!

Comment: how can i get value from from this column?

Comment: my problem is solved by now i want to get value from this column. please tell me how can i get?

Comment: @user3696811 - `string marks = listView1.Items[item_index].SubItems[2].Text;`